# Wordpress Options Framework Plugin Illegal String Warnings

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme I purchased a while back that is no longer being supported by the author. The theme functions great and I would like to keep using it for the foreseeable future. However, I recently noticed there are several PHP warnings taking place on the site stemming from the Options Framework Plugin.

Below is an example of one of the warnings:

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
> /removed-for-this-post/functions.php on line 590

And here is the code it is related to:

```
588 $heading_weights = of_get_option( 'heading_font_weights', options_typography_get_font_weights() );
589 $body_weights = of_get_option( 'body_font_weights', options_typography_get_font_weights() );
590 $heading_weights_values = array_keys($heading_weights, true);
```

Line 590 is the issue.

When I do a var_dump of `$heading_weights` it outputs `string(401) " 1 1"`.

This was all ready on earlier versions of PHP and the warnings are now showing on PHP 7.4.3. How can I adjust to fix the warnings?

Comment: `" 1 1"` is hardly 401 bytes long, so there's probably a lot of "invisible" stuff in there. Apply htmlspecialchars and see what this value looks like then. If not much changes, apply urlencode.

Comment: @CBroe - I tried both of those and it didn't output anything helpful. Any other idea?

Comment: Try urlencode, that should show you what byte values you are dealing with (via the percent hex encoding.)